# Can't access jQuery events on object

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I'm trying to check the events that are attached to an object in its event handler. Why is the check below yielding undefined?

HTML:

```
<button>Print out events in console</button>
```

JS:

```
$('button').on('click', function(ev) {
    console.dir($._data($(ev.target), 'events')); // undefined -- Why?
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ke36mr41/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It must be like the below as the first argument is a `DOM` element:

```
$('button').on('click.myNamespace', function(ev) {
    console.dir($._data(ev.target, 'events')); // undefined -- Why?
});
```

> More info from [jQuery Blog](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/09/jquery-1-8-released/) **$(element).data(“events”)**: In version 1.6, jQuery separated its internal data from the user’s data to prevent name collisions. However, some people were using the internal undocumented “events” data structure so we made it possible to still retrieve that via .data(). This is now removed in 1.8, but you can still get to the events data for debugging purposes via $._data(element, "events"). Note that this is not a supported public interface; the actual data structures may change incompatibly from version to version.

Comment: Whereas in previous versions of jQuery (the 1.x branch), it supported both. Nice catch. Of course, **`_data` is undocumented**, so caveat user.

Answer (score 2):

The element which you pass to `_data` method should be an html element but you are passing a jQuery object. Try this.

```
$('button').on('click.myNamespace', function(ev) {
    console.dir($._data(ev.target, 'events')); // undefined -- Why?
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

https://jsfiddle.net/ke36mr41/2/

```
$('button').on('click.myNamespace', function(ev) {
    console.dir($._data(ev.target, 'events')); // undefined -- Why?
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
 jQuery._data( elem, "events" );
```

Because`elem` should be an HTML element I suggest you to do this before:

```
var elem = createElement("div");
elem.innerHtml = $('button').html();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working

```
jQuery._data( $('button').get(0), "events" )
```